# jQuery - Handle a specific form among so many others

Tags: jquery, submit, selector, multiple-forms

I know a lot of people have created topics for this point : "handling multiple forms on same page". Nevertheless, after having reading most of them, I didn't find a solution.

I have a page which lists some articles. The user is able to give a mark on each post thanks to a slider and then submit it.
In order to submit the mark associated to the article, I use the function .each() but I don't have the expected result : it's the last form of my page which is submitted, whatever the form I submit.

HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="" class="vote-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" class="hidden" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="post_vote" value="VOTE">
</form>
```

JS :

```
$( ".vote-form" ).each(function() {

    $( this ).submit(function() {

        // get all the inputs into an array.
        var $inputs = $('.vote-form :input');

        // get an associative array of just the values.
        var values = {};
        $inputs.each(function() {
            values[this.name] = $(this).val();
            alert(values[this.name]);
        });

        // ************ Save vote in AJAX *************
        // ...

        return false;
    });
});
```

The alert displays each value of the hidden inputs when I submit one of the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the `input`s for the determined element. You can use `.find()` for it.

```
$( ".vote-form" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.submit(function() {
        // get all the inputs into an array.
        var $inputs = $this.find(':input');
        ...
```

You were grabbing all the existent `input` elements and I suspect that because of this during the associative array creation the elements with same `this.name` were being overwritten as you were processing the list of matched elements.

By the way, you can drop the `.each()` since `.submit()` works over the set of matched elements.

**Note:** I cached `$(this)` here.

Comment: Thx for your clear explanations. It seems to be good :)
What is the benefit of catching $(this) ?

Comment: @AdrienG, you mean "cache". Less DOM calls

Comment: Yeah sorry... It was late when I added this comment. Ok good to know !

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it displays all the data, since you are using an `each()` loop on all elements with the class `vote-form`. If you only want the submitted form to show, just drop the each and use a single submit event trigger instead, like:

```
$('.vote-form').submit(function() {

    // get all the inputs into an array.
    var $inputs = $(this).find(':input'); // Get all input fields of "this" specific form

    // get an associative array of just the values.
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        alert(values[this.name]);
    });

    // ************ Save vote in AJAX *************
    // ...

    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Alexander Ehhhh yeah that was sloppy. My bad, fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: My downvote is locked. Anyways, your argument seems incorrect though :|

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` from the main parent element, in your case the form, and you will isolate the search to the particular instance you are working with

```
 var $inputs = $(this).find(':input');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the context.
By selecting your inputs with

```
var $inputs = $('.vote-form :input');
```

you don't tell jQuery about the specific form so it selects all inputs that has class ".vote-form". I prefer to pass the context within the jQuery-Selector.
So it should look like this:

```
var $inputs = $(':input', $(this));
```

By using `this` you can get the form object inside the submit method.

working js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/282/

Comment: `$('.vote-form :input', $(this))` won't work, neither `$('.vote-form :input', this)` which it is the same :)

Comment: @Alexander  not sure why you say it won't work... is valid regardless of extra `$()` or not

Comment: @charlietfl, you should try it. I think it is faster that way

Comment: it works but i had a little mistake in my code. you just have to select ':input' because it only selects the children of the context. and the form $(this) has no child with class .vote-form.